# Custom Android keyboard: how to get cursor position updates in InputMethodService?

Tags: android

I want to know when the cursor position in custom Android keyboard changed.  There are `onUpdateCursor` and `onUpdateCursorAnchorInfo` methods, but they are not called when I override these methods in my InputMethodService:

```
class MyIMS : InputMethodService() {

    // ...

    override fun onUpdateCursorAnchorInfo(cursorAnchorInfo: CursorAnchorInfo?) {
        Log.e("test", "test")
        super.onUpdateCursorAnchorInfo(cursorAnchorInfo)
    }

}
```

According [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService#onUpdateCursorAnchorInfo(android.view.inputmethod.CursorAnchorInfo)) "This is **only called if explicitly requested by the input method**." So how can I *request* that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found it.

```
currentInputConnection.requestCursorUpdates(CURSOR_UPDATE_MONITOR)
```

Comment: This works fine for *some* textfields, but it fails on every Jetpack-Compose TextField.